# Styled components error with react-is. How can I correct this?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

[erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB7k9.png)

My program keeps throwing this error ever since I used react-tabs to create 4 components. Tabs, TabList, Tab and TabPanel as wrappers for my html.[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WglZJ.png). Please help me

Comment: please show your imports

Comment: import React from "react"; 

import Layout from "./Components/layout";

import Profile from "./Components/profile";

import Repositories from "./Components/repositories";

import { ResetCSS } from "./global/resetCSS";

Comment: Don't printscreen textual errors. Copy the text here, so they are found by others when searching

Comment: Thanks for the note